# How to pass object as parameter in function

Tags: c++, oop

**Please take a look at this.  I have comments in the problem function and corresponding call in main.**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void givesomespace()
{
    cout<<"------------------------NEW RESULTS BELOW------------------------"<<endl;
}


class squareMatrix 
{
public:

    squareMatrix();
    void makeEmpty(int n);
    void storeValue(int i, int j, int value);
    void print(int n);
    void add(squareMatrix matrix1, squareMatrix matrix2, squareMatrix result, int n);
    void subtract();
    void copy();
    int getvalue(int b,int c);

private:

    int matrix[10][10];
};

squareMatrix::squareMatrix()
{
}

void squareMatrix::makeEmpty(int n)
{
    for (int counter=0;counter<n;counter++)
    {
        for (int counter2=0;counter2<n;counter2++)
        {
            matrix[counter][counter2]=0;
        }
    }
}

void squareMatrix::print(int n)
{
    for (int counter=0;counter<n;counter++)
    {
        for (int counter2=0;counter2<n;counter2++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[counter][counter2]<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void squareMatrix::storeValue(int i, int j, int value)
{
    matrix[i][j]=value;
}

void squareMatrix::add(squareMatrix matrix1, squareMatrix matrix2, squareMatrix result,    int n)//-------------------PROBLEMS
{
    for (int counter=0;counter<n;counter++)
    {
        for (int counter2=0;counter2<n;counter2++)
        {
            result[counter][counter2] = (matrix1.getvalue(counter,counter2)+matrix2.getvalue(counter,counter2));
        }
    }
} //-----------------------------

void squareMatrix::subtract()
{

}

void squareMatrix::copy()
{

}

int squareMatrix::getvalue(int b, int c);
{
    return matrix[b][c];
}


main()
{
    squareMatrix matrix1,matrix2,result;
    matrix1.makeEmpty(5);
    matrix1.print(5);
    givesomespace();
    matrix1.storeValue(0,1,500);
    matrix1.print(5);
    givesomespace();
    matrix1.makeEmpty(5);
    matrix1.print(5);
    givesomespace();
    matrix2.storeValue(0,1,250);
    result.add(matrix1,matrix2,result,5); //------------corresponds with problem
    result.print(5);
    //result.subtract();
    //givesomespace();
    //result.print();
    //matrix2.storeValue(0,1,649)
    //matrix1.copy();
    //givesomespace();
    //matrix1.print();

    return(0);
}
```

It keeps throwing errors.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking, the question gives no indication of what your desired result is.

Comment: How did this get a "+1"?!

Comment: You are not making yourself especially clear, but maybe you want the `result` parameter to the `add` function to be by reference? So, `squareMatrix& result` rather than `squareMatrix result`?

Comment: "Please take a look at this." I wouldn't mind, but please make yourself clear first. "Corresponds with the problem" doesn't mean *anything*. What is this problem? Does the program crash? Does it hang? Does it give the wrong result? Does it fail to compile? Be precise.

Comment: ok here's the deal.  I would really like the make the add function work without creating more than one private array.  The function is supposed to add the elements from the array in object matrix1 to the array in object matrix2 and store them in the object result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know the concept of pass by value and pass by reference, e.g:

```
class A;
f(A& x);
```

using a '&' sign to declare that here the parameter is using "itself", not a copy.

more, if you are just using a parameter without changing any value of it. using const before parameter type.

e.g:

```
void f(const int& x) { x = 0; }
```

this cannot be compiled because of x cannot be assigned as a const parameter.

Comment: yes.  fixed code is below.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
                     void squareMatrix::subtract(squareMatrix matrix1, squareMatrix matrix2, squareMatrix &result, int n)
                    {
                         int temp;
                        for (int counter=0;counter<n;counter++)
                        {
                            for (int counter2=0;counter2<n;counter2++)
                            {
                               temp=(matrix1.getvalue(counter,counter2)- matrix2.getvalue(counter,counter2));
                               result.storeValue(counter,counter2,temp);

                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: here is the fixed code in case anybody ever wants it